# Using Gzip/Deflate with Codeigniter for better performance

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2, gzip, mod-deflate

I'm using Codeigniter a PHP framework and apache2.
  I have enabled Gzip and deflate mod in apache2 and its showing phpinfo(). When I run Yslow it shows  "**Grade F on Compress components with gzip**".
Even I changed the config.php of Codeigniter
`$config['compress_output'] = TRUE;`

but there is no effect. Is any thing I'm missing.

Comment: same question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973969/yslow-gives-f-grade-to-files-compressed-with-mod-deflate

Comment: The above problem was coming due to proxy. In my case i don't have any proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should enable mod_deflate just for CSS, html, js.

Ex:

```
<ifmodule deflate_module>
    DeflateCompressionLevel 1
    DeflateBufferSize 8096
    DeflateMemLevel 8
    DeflateWindowSize 8

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</ifmodule>
```

Because images or videos are already compressed and also they take a lot of time to try to compress.
Also there is a compress option on php.ini

Maybe it helps...

Comment: <ifmodule deflate_module.c>

Comment: this file where I put

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```